# Don't show a running application in the launcher (PyQt4)

Tags: unity, launcher, python, pyqt

I write an application that has an icon in the upper right corner in the notification area,
so there is no need to put its icon in the launcher.

But it is automatically put there.
How do I disable that (in code, not X)? I write this in python with Qt, PyQt4.